# Javascript - add same properties with different values

Tags: javascript, oop, object

***Important : the code works, so this is more a "is this the correct way?" question.***

I was trying to add different values to my object properties within a function and push it to an array then.
The object properties should remain the same but the name should be changed.

Output:

```
Object { 
  clientId="cXbHV32Sz0gh-10Mo6DX", 
  userName="Foo"
}, 
Object { 
  clientId="J3ZkTsK6ixTM6pUBo6DY", 
  userName="bar"
```

I was only able to achieve it with this solution:

```
var clientObj =  function (clientId, userName){
    var that = this;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.user
}

function myFunc(socket.id, userName){
    var clientInfo = new clientObj(socket.id, userName)
    clientList.push(clientInfo)
}
```

I wonder if I really need to have a constructor here, which does nothing than save my properties.

How can I achieve this without using a Constructor then?

I thought of something like this (but this does only replace the values) :

```
var ClientObj = {}

function myFunc(socketId, userName){
  ClientObj['socketID'] = socketID
  ClientObj['userName'] = userName
  clientList.push(clientObj)
}
```

Sorry if this might be a bit confusing

Comment: Why do you think that's a good way to do it? What part about your approach makes you uneasy?

Comment: I don't know if this is a good way to do it. 
I'd like to know if it is really necessary to create a new object everytime, maybe it's also possible to do this in a for loop or something like that?

Comment: Well that depends on _what else_ you are doing with these objects.  If `ClientObj` instances don't have methods than you don't need a constructor.

Comment: no it does not have any methods it just a container for my values, thats why I wondering if I should use constructor here

Comment: Looks like clientList will have several ClientInfo instances so you can stick with the constructor function. This is a good place to validate the data that it's storing. If you define ClientInfo outside of myFunc and change it then all the instances in clientList will be changed, you want ClientInfo to be unique every time myFunc is called then declare ClientInfo as an object literal in myFunc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few small things.  Your `that` variable is useless at the moment.  Usually something like that is used when you need to keep a reference to you object in an Ajax callback.

- clientObj should be capitalized since it's a constructor function.
- Consider making clientObj a function declaration so it'll be hoisted, which may or may not be important to you.

So maybe something like this

```
function ClientObj(clientId, userName){
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.user = userName;
}
```

Also, this is invalid:

```
function myFunc(socket.id, userName){
```

I think you meant something like this:

```
function myFunc(socketId, userName){
```

Comment: Hi Adams,
thanks for you hints, so there is no way to achieve this with some kind of for loop?

Comment: @ChristophHa - of course you can.  You can certainly create objects and push them to an array in a loop

Comment: @Christoph: I'm perhaps missing something, but could you (in your question) explain clearly, and precisely, what it is that you want to do? What is that's wrong, inefficient or problematic with the code you have that you'd rather change to do 'better' or differently?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right. You want to use some external object with the same values but different property names and push it to an array. In this case I'd write something like:

```
function Client(obj) {
    this.clientId = obj.clientId;
    this.user = obj.userName;
    return this;
}

Client.prototype.pushTo = function(arr) {
    arr.push(this);
    return this;
};

var clientList = [];
```

Then, when I receive an object:

```
var externalObj = { clientId: 'blah', userName: 'name' };
```

I could call:

```
var convertedClient = new Client(externalObj).pushTo(clientList);
```

You'd get it converted, pushed to the array and assigned it to local variable all with the same one liner. Also, if you later on figure new actions to perform with the  same type, you can add them.

```
Client.prototype.clearName = function(){
    this.name = '';
    return this;
};
```

If you keep on returning this from your prototypes, you can chain a lot of commands one after another.

```
var processedClient = new Client(obj).pushTo(arr).clearName();
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but there's something to think about. Going through a custom type and having to call a constructor doesn't sound so bad anymore.

---

**UPDATE:**

---

Just out of the fun of it, I decided to do this fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3eA5/